# Consuming a SOAP Rails Webservice doesn't work in Delphi 2009 but was Ok in Delphi 2006

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delphi, soap, web-services, delphi-2009

I have a soap webservice written in RubyOnRails and a client written in Delphi. The client and server comunicate fine using Delphi 2006, but compiling with the newer Delphi 2009 causes the Rails server to "crash".

This is the request (generated by built in THTTPRIO):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><SOAP-ENV:Body SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><NS1:IsValidCouponCode xmlns:NS1="urn:ActionWebService"><coupon_code xsi:type="xsd:string">1VK3K-7N45K-4V76W-JCS2F-NC125</coupon_code></NS1:IsValidCouponCode></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

This is the "response" of the Rails webservice

```
Internal protocol error: Bad encoding name "UTF-8"
Backtrace:
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rexml/encoding.rb:31:in `encoding='
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rexml/source.rb:54:in `encoding='
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/xsd/xmlparser/rexmlparser.rb:24:in `do_parse'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/soap/parser.rb:92:in `parse'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/soap/processor.rb:39:in `unmarshal'
[...]
```

So it seems clear that something with "UTF-8" encoding is different in Delphi 2009, but I have no idea how to change this.

Comment: Since you do not specify how you call the webservice, it is some gueswork:

It looks like your request is not specifying the encoding, and that Rails then expects the UTF8 encoding.

I suspect that with Delphi 2009 it now sends the data in UTF-16 encoding.

When you tell us how you actually send the request to the webservice, then we can try to solve it.

Comment: I use the default way to call the webservice via THTTPRio (the Delphi generated interface for the WSDL)

Comment: Thanks. Now can you get us the WSDL or a public URL where the service runs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. After comparing the requests which were basically the same (Delphi 2006 only had some more linebreaks and indentions in the xml) I found the difference in the HTTP-Header (using Wireshark)

Delphi 2006: Content-Type: text/xml
Delphi 2009: Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"

The Solution:

```
RIO.HTTPWebNode.UseUTF8InHeader := False;
```

The default value for this property had changed from Delphi 2006 to Delphi 2009

Conclusion:
It seems to be a bug in Ruby (on Rails). It worked with both Delphi-Versions with a local installation of the webservice on a Windows machine. Only the production machine running Linux had the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without more information...
Did you just recompile the code or **have you re-imported the WSDL in D2009?**
There is a good chance that you get 1 using WideString when the other plain string.
And you may have a difference between implicit vs explicit string conversion that you overlooked.

Comment: Yes, I reimported the wsdl. The only change was WideString turning into string, but the result (error) was the same.